# Rewriting require syntax with import keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

The package [gulp-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-help) gives the following example for requiring it:

```
// gulpfile.js 
var gulp = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp'));
```

The rest of my project is using the `import` keyword. Thus I would like to rewrite this to import as well.

Is this possible when the module exports like `module.exports = function (gulp, options) { ..`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it has to be a little more verbose:

```
import gulpHelp from 'gulp-help'
import _gulp from 'gulp'
var gulp = gulpHelp(_gulp)
```